# Топологическая сортировка в направленном ациклицеском графе

Tags: алгоритм

Всем привет.
Пытаюсь разработать алгоритм, который будет определять, является ли данная последовательность вершин топологической сортировкой для ДАГ. В общем, суть проблемы понятна, но все проблема в том, что сложность не должна превышать `О(E+V)`, а у меня это никак не получается. Может у кого-то есть какие-то идеи или подсказки.

*Вариант решения*

Можно так - удаляете вершины из исходного графа в порядке, заданном входной последовательностью. Перед удалением вершины проверяете, что у нее нет входящих дуг (если есть - то заданная последовательность не является топологической сортировкой), после удаления удаляете все исходящие дуги. Все.

Думаю, это имеет сложность выше, не так ли?

Comment: Вроде все правильно. O(E+V) и выходит по кол-ву операций удаления.

Comment: @a_gurа, мне кажется нет. Удаление ребра графа обычно не O(1). Хотя если списки смежности являются хэш-таблицами, то наверное такая сложность достигается.

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно удалять ребра. Можно просто помечать пройденные вершины, и проверять, что у очередной вершины нет входящих ребер из не помеченных вершин.